# Copy List to Different List Using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-4

I have an entity from database and I want to copy the data into another `class` having the following fields. here it is

```
var list = mediaItems.Select(m => new MediaItemView
                {
                    ImageUrl = m.ImageURL,
                    LongDesc = m.LongDescription,
                    Title = m.Title,
                    Price = m.PriceNoVAT,
                    Composer = m.MediaItemOriginators.Where(mo => mo.OriginatorType.OriginatorTypeId == 3).FirstOrDefault().Originator.Firstname,
                    Arranger = m.MediaItemOriginators.Where(mo => mo.OriginatorType.OriginatorTypeId == 2).FirstOrDefault().Originator.Firstname,
                });
```

**Problem:** When the `Composer = m.MediaItemOriginators.Where(mo => mo.OriginatorType.OriginatorTypeId == 3).FirstOrDefault()` is null I get exception (it's normal), but I want to have the Composer if there is any or if not - an empty string .
**How to achieve this any idea?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would change to use a `Select` clause to select the name before the `FirstOrDefault` or default call, then use the null coalescing operator:

```
Composer = m.MediaItemOriginators
            .Where(mo => mo.OriginatorType.OriginatorTypeId == 3)
            .Select(mo => m.Originator.Firstame)
            .FirstOrDefault() ?? ""
```

(That's assuming that `m.Originator` is never null for matching entries, of course.)

Or you could use `DefaultIfEmpty` followed by just `First`:

```
Composer = m.MediaItemOriginators
            .Where(mo => mo.OriginatorType.OriginatorTypeId == 3)
            .Select(mo => m.Originator.Firstame)
            .DefaultIfEmpty("")
            .First()
```